# Jquery Chosen with Parsley

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen, parsley.js

I am trying to use chosen in a form that is part of an application but I also need form validation. ParsleyJS does seem to work with chosen but ParsleyJS is applying the error class to the hidden  element instead of the actual control the user sees. Is there any way to make these two play along a bit better? It would be awesome if this could work since it seems like chosen is the only class that works at all with any validation libraries that I have tested.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      input.parsley-success,
      select.parsley-success,
      textarea.parsley-success {
        color: #468847;
        background-color: #DFF0D8;
        border: 1px solid #D6E9C6;
      }
      
      input.parsley-error,
      select.parsley-error,
      textarea.parsley-error {
        color: #B94A48;
        background-color: #F2DEDE;
        border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
      }
      
      .parsley-errors-list {
        margin: 2px 0 3px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        line-height: 0.9em;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all .3s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
      }
      
      .parsley-errors-list.filled {
        opacity: 1;
      }

    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.0/parsley.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#identifier').chosen();
        $('#ticketform').parsley();
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="ticketform" name="ticketform" action="open_ticket.php" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Please select or enter an IP address:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <select name="identifier" id="identifier" data-parsley-errors-container="#select-errors" required="">
            <option value="" selected>Please enter or select IP address</option>
            <option value="4.4.4.4">4.4.4.4</option>
            <option value="8.8.8.8">8.8.8.8</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div id="select-errors" />
      </div>
      <input id="button" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit ticket">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should customize `data-parsley-errors-container`.